# MSI laptop battery capacity issues

Tags: 22.04, battery, msi

I have an issue with battery capacity on my MSI Modern 15 A11M laptop.
Laptop is not so old, just about a year of using.
And there is an issue with battery capacity.
Each time after laptop reboot, `upower -i` gives me different capacity percentage, from 50+% to 90+%.
And laptop is taking that capacity numbers seriously, so sometimes notebook can live like 2hrs from battery, and sometimes 5hrs (using same working scenarios), depending on capacity value.
So I'm wondering if somebody can help me with this?
Thanks in advance.
Here is some laptop info. If additional outputs needed - pls let me know.

```
System:
  Kernel: 5.15.0-52-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 11.2.0 Desktop: Cinnamon 5.4.12
    tk: GTK 3.24.33 wm: Mutter dm: LightDM Distro: Linux Mint 21 Vanessa base: Ubuntu 22.04 jammy
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: Micro-Star product: Modern 15 A11M v: REV:1.0 serial: <superuser required>
    Chassis: type: 10 serial: <superuser required>
  Mobo: Micro-Star model: MS-1552 v: REV:1.0 serial: <superuser required>
    UEFI: American Megatrends LLC. v: E1552IMS.121 date: 04/13/2022
Battery:
  ID-1: BAT1 charge: 39.5 Wh (96.3%) condition: 41.0/52.4 Wh (78.2%) volts: 11.8 min: 11.4
    model: MSI Corp. MS-1552 serial: N/A status: Discharging
CPU:
  Info: quad core model: 11th Gen Intel Core i7-1165G7 bits: 64 type: MT MCP arch: Tiger Lake
    rev: 1 cache: L1: 320 KiB L2: 5 MiB L3: 12 MiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 1149 high: 1243 min/max: 400/4700 cores: 1: 956 2: 1121 3: 1243 4: 1222
    5: 1223 6: 1212 7: 1087 8: 1135 bogomips: 44851
  Flags: avx avx2 ht lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel TigerLake-LP GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics] vendor: Micro-Star MSI driver: i915
    v: kernel ports: active: eDP-1 empty: DP-1, DP-2, DP-3, DP-4, HDMI-A-1 bus-ID: 00:02.0
    chip-ID: 8086:9a49
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.3 driver: X: loaded: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa
    gpu: i915 display-ID: :0 screens: 1
  Screen-1: 0 s-res: 1920x1080 s-dpi: 96
  Monitor-1: eDP-1 model: AU Optronics res: 1920x1080 dpi: 142 diag: 394mm (15.5")
  OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel Xe Graphics (TGL GT2) v: 4.6 Mesa 22.0.5 direct render: Yes
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Audio vendor: Micro-Star MSI
    driver: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl bus-ID: 00:1f.3 chip-ID: 8086:a0c8
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.15.0-52-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 15.99.1 running: yes
  Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.48 running: yes
Network:
  Device-1: Intel Wi-Fi 6 AX201 driver: iwlwifi v: kernel bus-ID: 00:14.3 chip-ID: 8086:a0f0
  IF: wlo1 state: up mac: <filter>
  IF-ID-1: docker0 state: down mac: <filter>
Bluetooth:
  Device-1: Intel AX201 Bluetooth type: USB driver: btusb v: 0.8 bus-ID: 3-10:2 chip-ID: 8087:0026
  Report: hciconfig ID: hci0 rfk-id: 2 state: up address: <filter> bt-v: 3.0 lmp-v: 5.2
    sub-v: 237e
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 476.94 GiB used: 227.6 GiB (47.7%)
  ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Kingston model: OM8PCP3512F-AI1 size: 476.94 GiB speed: 31.6 Gb/s
    lanes: 4 serial: <filter> temp: 24.9 C
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 467.89 GiB used: 227.6 GiB (48.6%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/nvme0n1p2
  ID-2: /boot/efi size: 511 MiB used: 5.2 MiB (1.0%) fs: vfat dev: /dev/nvme0n1p1
Swap:
  ID-1: swap-1 type: file size: 16 GiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%) priority: -2 file: /swapfile
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 43.0 C mobo: N/A
  Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A
Info:
  Processes: 335 Uptime: 18h 9m Memory: 15.34 GiB used: 4.99 GiB (32.5%) Init: systemd v: 249
  runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: 11.3.0 alt: 11/9 Client: Cinnamon v: 5.4.12 inxi: 3.3.13
```

upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT1:

```
native-path:          BAT1
  vendor:               MSI Corp.
  model:                MS-1552
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Mon 31 Oct 2022 01:32:44 PM EET (27 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               discharging
    warning-level:       none
    energy:              39,2844 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         40,9944 Wh
    energy-full-design:  52,44 Wh
    energy-rate:         8,2194 W
    voltage:             11,836 V
    charge-cycles:       N/A
    time to empty:       4,8 hours
    percentage:          95%
    capacity:            77,9783%
    technology:          lithium-ion
    icon-name:          'battery-full-symbolic'
  History (charge):
    1667215964  95,000  discharging
  History (rate):
    1667215964  8,219   discharging
```

So the question is - how to make battery capacity to be "relatively static", and not change from boot to boot by 20-30%. Thanks.

Comment: why do you think it *is* fully charged?

Comment: What do you mean? I am talking about battery capacity, not charge level.
On output you can see that it is charged for 95%, but capacity is 73% (from design capacity). Today it shows 63% of capacity. As I said above - it changes in 50%-90% range each time after reboot (almost each time).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: this looks very much like a hardware issue, or at the very least a BIOS issue. Ubuntu just gets info about battery capacity from the BIOS afaik. Try resetting your BIOS or contact the manufacturer.

Comment: I thought so too. And I have updated BIOS to latest version from MSI official site, but nothing changed. I'm about to install windows for dual boot, and check if that problem is present there too. It's really annoying, today laptop just shut down while there were 30% charge left according to UI. After that I plugged in charger, turn on the laptop, and upower now shows me 37% of capacity...